# How to avoid multiple redirect_to when called inside a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I've got a little issue with rails, I want to be able to do something like this to avoid multiple redirections :

```
def render_not_found
  not_found
end

private

  def not_found
    redirect_to website_url(@website), :status => 301 and return return
  end
```

`return return` doesn't work of course!

Using: rails 3.2.0

Comment: Why are you redirecting to a `website_url` if something wasn't found?  What wasn't found that causes that redirect to happen?  Please explain your logic a bit more and then maybe we can better help.

Comment: not_found is called everywhere in my app. website_url(@website) is just the homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. One way is to define and raise a custom error, and have a handler that redirects when that happens.

application_controller.rb

```
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_filter :catch_errors

  def catch_errors
    yield
  rescue SiteNotFoundError
    redirect_to website_url(@website), :status => 301
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render 404
  rescue ...
    ...
    ...
  end
end

class SiteNotFoundError < StandardError; end
```

in your controller

```
def your_action
  raise SiteNotFoundError if (some condition)
end
```

or in a before filter

```
before_filter :ensure_valid_site

def ensure_valid_site
  raise SiteNotFoundError if ....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my redirections for errors in before_filters.

But if you really want to do this, you can do it like this... but I'm warning you
it ain't pretty.

```
def render_not_found
  not_found(binding)
end

private

def not_found(b)
  redirect_to website_url(@website), :status => 301
  b.eval('return')
end
```